# Node goes down during upgrade

Tags: cassandra

We have a fairly large 2.0.x cassandra cluster in the cloud, around 60 nodes, and we're going through the process of running test upgrades on test clusters to get familiar with the process.

We plan to upgrade an availability zone at a time as a way to mitigate risk having the whole process maybe take a couple days.  We're following the procedure in the datastax PDF documentation attached to this page (https://docs.genesys.com/Special:Repository/Cassandra%20Upgrade%20Guide.pdf?id=435716573909&page=Documentation:CR:Solution:UpgradingCassandraTo2x:8.5.2).

I understand that there can not be any bootstraps for nodes during the time the cluster is being upgraded, so I was wondering what is the procedure if we have a hardware failure where the VM is taken out of service? Essentially what is the procedure for if a node goes down in the cluster while it's in a partial upgrade state?

Would we perform a `nodetool removenode <hostid>` followed with a `nodetool removenode force` and continue on with the upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would we perform a `nodetool removenode <hostid>` followed with a `nodetool removenode force` and continue on with the upgrade?

Except for the `removenode force`, that's what I would do.  `nodetool removenode` attempts to move data from the additional, non-primary token ranges to the other nodes to ensure that the RF can be met.  This way you're absolutely sure that you won't lose data.

Comment: Okay good.  I attempted to do just that and the process stalled.  There was a bunch of stack traces due to SSL during the remove node process.. I think these stack traces were related to talking to the updated nodes.  We run SSL between the nodes and it seems like a bug with SSL between 2.0 and 2.1.  Either way, something to force us to expedite the process of upgrading

Comment: @Bob ok, if it stalls and you see that data isn’t streaming, then it’s totally ok to kill it.